# Is there anyway i could create a transparent root element?

Tags: javafx-2

I want to create a borderpane what is transparent.I tried setting background color to transparent but it appears white. plz let me know if there is a way.

Code i tried.

```
 BorderPane root=new BorderPane();
 root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent");
 Scene scene=new Scene(root);
 stage.setScene(scene);
 stage.show();
```

Thank you...

Comment: Are you sure the background of your window isn't already white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the stage to transparent:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class TransparentStage extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // important line
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

        Text text = new Text("Transparent!");
        text.setFont(new Font(40));
        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(text);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box,300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. Statement I was looking for was scene.setFill(null);